# ¿Cómo pasar todos los parámetros de un script bash a otro script/programa?

Tags: bash

Quiero pasar todos los parámetros que recibe un script bash a otro script o programa. Pero no quiero pasarle el parámetro 0, que contiene el nombre con que ha sido invocado el script bash.

Si supiese que lo invocan con 3 parámetros tal que así:

```
mi_script a b c
```

podría usar el siguiente script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
otro_script_o_programa "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

Pero eso no me sirve si el script va a recibir un número arbitrario de parámetros, que puede incluso ser ninguno.
Es importante que se trate correctamente los parámetros que contienen espacios, tabuladores, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso se usa "$@" que significa "todos los parámetros que recibí".

En tu caso, el contenido de mi_script sería

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
otro_script_o_programa "$@"
```

**Edit**: originalmente había propuesto utilizar $@ de manera no entrecomillada, lo cual lleva a que, dado un parámetro con la forma de un string entrecomillado, los espacios dentro de éste harán que cada palabra se considere un nuevo parámetro. Con la opción "$@" esto no sucede y se pasa literalmente cada parámetro entrecomillado a la siguiente función.

Comment: has sido ninja'd por 50 segundos hahaha

Comment: bien jugado, te daré upvote

Comment: hahaha no es necesario, pero gracias. voto pa ti tambien hahah pude haberme demorado lo justo y tu respuesta es valida

Comment: Lo he probado y no funciona bien. Si invoco mi script con `mi_script "hola adios"` entonces a `otro_script_o_programa` le llegan los argumentos partidos como "hola" y "adios" cuando tendría que llegar como un solo argumento "hola adios"

Comment: ahh cierto, olvidaste las comillas. ni lo vi xD

Comment: es verdad. Si quieres que bash respete los argumentos entrecomillados, tienes que usar "$@". De lo contrario los espacios indican un nuevo parámetro.

Comment: Te convendría editar la respuesta para poner las comillas, amenadiel. Así podría votarte positivo.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos ya está

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como dicen en [esta pregunta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824590/propagate-all-arguments-in-a-bash-shell-script):

Has de pasar `"$@"`

```
otro_script_o_programa "$@"
```

Comment: Lo he probado y funciona bien. Gracias y +1.