# Cómo enviar varias variables a un comando en un shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Estoy haciendo un script para la shell de Linux y no funciona como debería una opción. Esto se debe a que solo detecta una variable cuando le mando 2 al comando.

He aquí el ejemplo:

```
echo "introduce el numero"
read $fecha
chage -m $fecha $usuario2
```

¿Alguien sabe solucionar esto?

Comment: o sea quieres que al preguntar por `$fecha` el read lea dos parámetros?

Comment: Puede que tu duda sea la misma que está respondida en esta pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49596/c%C3%B3mo-pasar-todos-los-par%C3%A1metros-de-un-script-bash-a-otro-script-programa/49599#49599

Comment: @amenadiel no, no es el mismo caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está a la hora de almacenar el contenido en la variable `fecha`.

En Bash/shell scripting la [asignación de variables](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/newbie_traps#setting_variables) se hace sin el símbolo `$`. Mientras que para mostrar el contenido sí que se utiliza el símbolo `$`:

```
mivariable="hola mundo"
echo $mivariable  # => hola mundo
```

Lo mismo ocurre con `read`. Por lo que el código debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
echo "introduce el numero"
read fecha
chage -m $fecha $usuario2
```

Saludos.